# Does charging a windows phone with a PC have any negative effect on the battery?

Tags: battery-life

My wall charger stopped working all of a sudden and my office is far from where I can get another one, the only option is to use my office PC to charge with the use of USB.
So, I'd like to know if there is any negative effect to my phone's battery life.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but it is definitely a slow charge.

[This](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-7/177925-usb-charging.html#post1542759) might also help you decide:

> Actually, USB ports are 5 volts DC versus 110-120 volts AC for wall
>   outlets in the US. But the issue here isn't voltage; it's current. USB
>   ports are 500-900 mA versus about 1.5A in most wall chargers. That's
>   up to three times more current than USB charging. More current, faster
>   charging, although I don't know that I'd go much higher than 1.5A and
>   risk damaging the battery.

Also check out some answers [here](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-charge-my-phone-by-computer-using-a-USB-or-directly-to-the-wall).

Comment: Charging with a lower current will cause less heat due to the internal resistance of the battery. Since heating is never good for electronics, keeping the battery cooler during charging should have the tendency to prolong the battery's life span. So I'm siding with the chemical engineer's opinion (behind the link). I'm no expert on battery technology, though...